# Indy UDP Server Event Handler / Memory Growth Problem

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

I have a small program which is stable under Delphi/VCL.  I have re-created it as a FireMonkey app, and although it runs, the memory used increases constantly until the app becomes unresponsive and crashes.

I have an Indy `TIdUDPServer` receiving SysLog messages.  Using the `OnUDPRead` event handler, I copy the `AData` to a `String` and call another procedure which dissects the string and outputs the results to a `TListBox`, (and posts to a database, although I have removed that function for clarity).

I believe the problem may be due to calling the `String` handling routine from the event handler which is running in a worker thread, which then adds items to the `TListBox`.

As a test, I have tried de-coupling the event handler from the subsequent operations by setting a global 'flag' to true in the event handler and using a timer, looking for the flag, and if set, call the handling routine so that the Indy event handler does not access any UI components.  However the memory growth still occurs.

Why does this program work OK when run as a VCL project, but not in FMX?

How can I avoid the memory growth problem in FMX??

```pascal
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  IP := ABinding.PeerIP;   // global string
  SysMsg := BytesToString(AData);// global string
  DataAvailable := True;    //   global semaphore variable
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DataAvailable then
  begin
    DataAvailable := False;
    ProcessMessage(IP, SysMsg);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ProcessMessage(IP, SysLogMsg: String);
begin
  //  Dissect Syslog string
  //  Add Items to listbox
  //  Post items to Database using FDCOnnection, FDQuery   (problem remains with this removed)
end;
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using `TIdSysLogServer` instead? In any case, there is nothing in the code shown that will cause memory issues. But what does `ProcessMessage()` actually look like? And what platform(s) are you seeing the memory issue on, exactly? Also, the `OnUDPRead` event is `Synchronize()`'d with the main UI thread by default, so there shouldn't be any issues with accessing the UI, unless you have set `TIdUDPServer.ThreadedEvent=True` to disable the use of `Synchronize()`. Without a [mcve], it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remy,  thanks for your reply.  Following your advice I pruned the ProcessMessage procedure down until I only had a few lines of code left and still had the memory growth problem. The smallest example I can give is below, simply using a timer to pump strings into a listbox.

The final line setting ListBox1.ItemIndex  causes the problem.  If I comment this out and recompile the memory problem goes away.  The example runs without the memory problem if I rebuild it as a VCL project.

I am using Delphi 10.4 and I ran the code on both Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2012 with the same results.

I notice that the FMX version uses about 10 times as much memory as the VCL version (running without the offending line), is this to be expected?

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ListBox1.items.add(FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', Now));

 while ListBox1.items.Count > 25 do
   ListBox1.items.Delete(0);

 ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.items.Count - 1;
end;
```

I did try using TIdSysLogServer but it raises a runtime error when trying to interpret a syslog message from A Cisco ASA firewall.

The timestamp in the Cisco syslog message looks like this:
2022-10-16T19:03:27+01:00:

Many Thanks